# How do I Uninstall NCH Software Components?

Tags: video-encoding, video-codecs

So I have a few components installed for VideoPad from [NCH Software Components Download](http://www.nch.com.au/components/)

Is there anyway to uninstall the profiles?

Answer (score 0):

The components can be found in this path:

> %appdata%\NCH Software\Components